# Laravel join with latest pressureMap entrance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 different MySQL tables with the following attributes:

**mattress:** id, healthSystemName, building, floor, room, bed, idUSer

**patient:** id, idMattress, name, surname

**pressuremap:** id, idMattress, pressureData, presence, created_at, updated_at

I want to get a list of all the mattresses existing with the following information to show it in the dashboard of my application developed in Laravel (PHP):

- It should be joined with the patient table (mattress.id =
  patient.idMattress).
- It should be joined with the pressuremap table (pressuremap.idMattress = mattress.id)
- I only need the information of the latest pressure map (order by pressure.created_at descendent, limit 1)
- Could be that the mattress has no patient assigned and/or pressuremap. In this case there should be a row with the values related to the patient and pressuremap as null
- The SELECT sholuld have: mattress.id, patient.name, patient.surname, preassuremap.presence, preassuremap.created_at

Right now, I managed to get the information of the mattress joined with the patients with the following function, but I need to add the pressuremap info:

```
public function index(){
        $id = Auth::id();

        $mattress = DB::table("mattress")
            ->leftJoin("patient","mattress.id","=","patient.idMattress")
            ->select("patient.id", "patient.name", "patient.surname", "patient.medicalRecordNumber", "patient.visitRecordNumber", "mattress.id", "mattress.healthSystemName","mattress.building","mattress.floor","mattress.room", "mattress.bed")
            ->where('mattress.idUser', '=', $id)
            ->get();

        return view('dashboard',['mattress' => $mattress]);
    }
```

How to get this data?

I add an image of how this information should be shown for better understanding, where I already have the green data and I need to add the yellow one:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
After digging a bit I found the way to add the latest pressureMap to the mattress but now I don't get the mattress that is empty.
Also I must mention that you need to set in the file config/database.php the mysql property 'strict' to false.

```
$latestPressureMap = DB::table('pressuremap')
        ->select('idMattress', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as last_pressureMap_created_at'), 'presence', 'maxPressure')
        ->groupBy('idMattress');

    $mattress = DB::table('mattress')
        ->joinSub($latestPressureMap, 'latest_pressureMap', function ($join) {
            $join->on('mattress.id', '=', 'latest_pressureMap.idMattress');
        })
        ->leftJoin("patient","mattress.id","=","patient.idMattress")
        ->select("patient.id", "patient.name", "patient.surname", "patient.medicalRecordNumber", "patient.visitRecordNumber", "mattress.id", "mattress.healthSystemName","mattress.building","mattress.floor","mattress.room", "mattress.bed", "patient.gender", "latest_pressureMap.presence", "latest_pressureMap.last_pressureMap_created_at","latest_pressureMap.maxPressure")
        ->where('mattress.idUser', '=', $id)
        ->get();

    return view('dashboard',['mattress' => $mattress]);
```

Comment: what have you tried? did you defined relationships with these 3 models?

Comment: I've just edited my post to show how I have it right now @arun

Comment: Are you familiar with Eloquent relationships?

Comment: not at all :( @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: I recommend you take a look at them, they make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the way:

```
$latestPressureMap = DB::table('pressuremap')
        ->select('idMattress', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as last_pressureMap_created_at'), 'presence', 'maxPressure')
        ->groupBy('idMattress');

    $mattress = DB::table('mattress')
        ->leftJoinSub($latestPressureMap, 'latest_pressureMap', function ($join) {
            $join->on('mattress.id', '=', 'latest_pressureMap.idMattress');
        })
        ->leftJoin("patient","mattress.id","=","patient.idMattress")
        ->select("patient.id", "patient.name", "patient.surname", "patient.medicalRecordNumber", "patient.visitRecordNumber", "mattress.id", "mattress.healthSystemName","mattress.building","mattress.floor","mattress.room", "mattress.bed", "patient.gender", "latest_pressureMap.presence", "latest_pressureMap.last_pressureMap_created_at","latest_pressureMap.maxPressure")
        ->where('mattress.idUser', '=', $id)
        ->get();

    return view('dashboard',['mattress' => $mattress]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$mattress = DB::table('mattress')->join('patient', 'mattress.id','=', 'patient.idMattress')
        ->where(['mattress.idUser' => $id])
        ->leftJoin('pressuremap', 'pressuremap.idMattress', '=', 'mattress.id')
        ->select("patient.id", "patient.name", "patient.surname", "mattress.id",
            "mattress.healthSystemName","mattress.building","mattress.floor","mattress.room",
            "mattress.bed", "pressuremap.pressureData", "pressuremap.presence",
            "pressuremap.created_at", "pressuremap.updated_at")
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();


    return view('dashboard',['mattress' => $mattress]);
}
```

I did not include patient.medicalRecordNumber and patient.visitRecordNumber in the select since you have not said that these columns exist in the patient table. If they do exist you can easily change the query.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. 
Unfortunetly, this doesn't work... The thing is that this is making a join with all the pressure maps but I want to make the join JUST with the latest pressure map of each mattress.

Comment: It doesn't crash but it is not what I need @Harry. As I told in my latest comment I need just to make the join with the latest pressure map, not with all of them

Comment: Achieving to get the latest pressure map in the join itself is not something I know how to do...